# Pass scroll events through canvas to div below

Tags: css, html, canvas

I want the text to scroll vertically no matter if the pointer is on top of the grey area (the container div) or the red area (the canvas element on top). Currently the canvas prevents the scroll events to be propagated below. Is there a CSS only solution to this?

See the [codepen](https://codepen.io/_miki_/pen/PxXZQL?editors=1100) and the image below.

[image]

This is my code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>
    blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>
    blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>
    blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>
    blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>
    blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>
  </div>
  <canvas class="overlay">
  </canvas>
</div>

.container {
    background: #CCCCCC;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    border: 4px black solid;
}
.content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
}
.overlay {
    border:1px solid black;
    background: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left:0;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
}
```

Comment: Do you also want the red square to scroll down or have a fixed position while text scrolls?

Comment: @GrandIQ The red square should be fixed on top. In my application, the canvas fully covers the div below. I use the canvas to draw some small interactive widgets, so the canvas should still receive clicks. What I need is the canvas to remain static on top while the content below scrolls if user scrolls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were so close.

You need to set the `position` to `fixed` on the `.container` class and then you will need to add `pointer-events: none;` to your `.overlay` class. That does the trick.

See below:

```css
.container {
    background: #CCCCCC;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: fixed;
    border: 4px black solid;
}
.content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
}
.overlay {
    border:1px solid black;
    background: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left:0;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>
    blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>
    blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>
    blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>
    blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>
    blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>
  </div>
  <canvas class="overlay">
  </canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Quinton. "pointer-events: none;" is all I need. Why are you suggesting to add "position: fixed;" as well?

Comment: @Miki `position: fixed` was more of a suggestion based off of an assumption that the overlay would remain fixed in a specific position. Remember to mark this as an answer to your question if it provided you with a solution.

Comment: Thanks. Your solution makes the canvas transparent to any type of events, not just scrolling. The user should be able to click on the canvas. Is there a way to selectively enable/disable scroll events only?

Comment: @Miki with CSS and pointer-events you are really only capable of turning off all pointer events, inheriting the parent, or leaving it as default - `auto`. If I understand more clearly what you are asking for then I believe that this is a proper solution for you. [CodePen Example](https://codepen.io/quinton_c/pen/dQwqmd)

Answer (score 4):

Instead of solving the problem you may avoid it. In the following example I'm using `pointer-events:none` for the canvas only on `wheel`. This will allow you to scroll through the canvas. However as soon as you click the `container` I'm deleting the inline styles for the canvas. Alternatively I could have written `test.style.pointerEvents = "initial"`

```js
test.addEventListener("wheel", ()=>{
  test.style.pointerEvents = "none";
  console.log("w")
})

container.addEventListener("click",(evt)=>{test.style.cssText = "";
                                      console.log(oMousePos(test, evt))})

function oMousePos(elmt, evt) {
      var ClientRect = elmt.getBoundingClientRect();
                return { //objeto
                x: Math.round(evt.clientX - ClientRect.left),
                y: Math.round(evt.clientY - ClientRect.top)
      }
}
```

```css
.container {
    background: #CCCCCC;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    border: 4px black solid;
}
.content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
}
.overlay {
    border:1px solid black;
    background: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left:0;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
  pointer-events:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="container">
  <div class="content">
    blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>
    blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>
    blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>
    blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>
    blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>
    blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>
  </div>
  <canvas class="overlay" id="test">
  </canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @enxaneta, very clever.

Answer (score 1):

Still requires js

It's a simpler version of [enxaneta answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53559527/3163120), but requires knowing beforehand which node will be scrolled

```js
overlay.addEventListener("wheel", (event)=>{
  scrollingNode.scroll({
    top: event.deltaY + scrollingNode.scrollTop,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
  event.preventDefault();
})
```

```css
.container {
    background: #CCCCCC;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    border: 4px black solid;
}
.content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
}
.overlay {
    border:1px solid black;
    background: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left:0;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
  pointer-events:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="container">
  <div class="content" id="scrollingNode">
    blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>
    blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>
    blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>
    blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>
    blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>
    blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>blah<br/>
  </div>
  <canvas class="overlay" id="overlay">
  </canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: In my case, `behavior: 'smooth'` made the scrolling inconsistent at higher scrolling speeds. Removing it fixed this issue.

Comment: @IgorGunin Interesting. I am in firefox, and if I remove `behavior: 'smooth'` the scrolling on top of the red area becomes instantaneous which is farther than the default behaviour